# Why am i getting this error when i try to play mp3 / wav sound file using SoundPool android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I am trying to use android SoundPool to play a button click sound here is my code :

```
fun play(view: View) {
    val sound = soundPool.load(this,R.raw.bc,1)
    soundPool.play(sound,1.0F,1.0F,0,0,1.0F)
}
```

But it's not playing the sound and when i use debugging mode i get the following error when i click the button :

```
W/MediaExtractor: creating media extractor in calling process
W/MediaExtractor: uid 10202.  not using HwExtendedExtractor 
I/MediaExtractor: content 'audio/x-wav' with conf 0.30
V/NuMediaExtractor: track of type 'audio/raw' does not publish bitrate
E/HwExtendedCodec: mime: audio/raw matching compontent failed!
I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
E/HwExtendedCodec: mime: video/avc matching compontent failed!
I/ACodec: In onAllocateComponent create compenent, codec name: OMX.google.raw.decoder
W/HwExtendedUtils: hw configLocalPlayBack err = -2147483648
I/ACodec: onStart
D/MediaBufferGroup: creating MemoryDealer
W/ACodec: forcing OMX state to Idle when received shutdown in ExecutingState
```

I was using mp3 file and this error occured then i thought the problem is in the sound type which mp3 so tried to use wav but i am getting the same error.

Comment: how long is your track that you are trying to play?

Comment: It's less than a second